# double click item in listview c#

Tags: c#, listview, double-click

i still cannot understand how to make the item in listview to be clickable and appear messagebox.

this is my code.

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem listviewitem;

        listviewitem = new ListViewItem("John");
        listviewitem.SubItems.Add("Smith");
        listviewitem.SubItems.Add("kaya");
        listviewitem.SubItems.Add("bun");
        this.listView1.Items.Add(listviewitem);
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
```

//show header
            listView1.View = View.Details;

```
        // Loop through and size each column header to fit the column header text.
        foreach (ColumnHeader ch in this.listView1.Columns)
        {
            ch.Width = -2;
        }
```

}

i have read itemActive and i have tried this. im adding `listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text`

```
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem listviewitem;

            listviewitem = new ListViewItem("John");
            listviewitem.SubItems.Add("Smith");
            listviewitem.SubItems.Add("kaya");
            listviewitem.SubItems.Add("bun");
            this.listView1.Items.Add(listviewitem);
            listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

            MessageBox.Show("You clicked " + listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
}
```

this printout error

> argument out of range. '0' is not valid number of index.

please help me with this.

Comment: why you not use .Listview Click event or slectedindexchanged event?

Comment: i did but it does not work and i do not want to change the index. all i want just click the list and it will popup the details of selected list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On `button6_Click()` only add newly created `listviewitem` in `listView1`

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem listviewitem;

    listviewitem = new ListViewItem("John");
    listviewitem.SubItems.Add("Smith");
    listviewitem.SubItems.Add("kaya");
    listviewitem.SubItems.Add("bun");
    this.listView1.Items.Add(listviewitem);
    listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

    //MessageBox.Show("You clicked " + listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
}
```

Register the `Click` event against `listView1`

```
this.listView1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.listView1_Click);
```

And in it's event handler check for `listView1.SelectedItems[0]`

```
private void listView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
             MessageBox.Show("You clicked " + listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
}
```

For documentation, [please check MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click)

Comment: may i ask, how to make register the click event against listView1?

Comment: As I mentioned you can add this.listView1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.listView1_Click); in your code. Or from designer select the list view, on the property window click on the events button. The list containing all the list view events will appear. Find out "Click" from the list and double click over it. The Click event will be registered and empty event handler will also be added.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually selected an item and thats when you get the error:

**InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.**

Put some protection to check an item is selected:

```
if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You clicked " + listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
}
else
{
     MessageBox.Show("Please select an item");
}
```

Or select the item in code:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem listviewitem;

        listviewitem = new ListViewItem("John");
        listviewitem.SubItems.Add("Smith");
        listviewitem.SubItems.Add("kaya");
        listviewitem.SubItems.Add("bun");
        this.listView1.Items.Add(listviewitem);
        //listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
        listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked " + listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
}
```

Comment: the first one, it popup the message "select an item" before i could even click any of the list.meanwhile, for the second way, i want user can click in any sub item for an item and above code it shows the message box first then it show the list. it is not what i want.

Comment: Both examples explain why you get the error. I thought it would be better for you to work out that you would need to populate the list with one event and in another event (ie ListItem_Click) you would show a messsagebox. @hamad has shown you what you want. May I suggest picking up on these [great books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books) as programming is too complex to `learn well` by *googling* or *as you go*. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is an active item?
Possibly because you have not selected any item in the list. Make a check on the selected items,

```
 string msg = (listView1.SelectedItems.Count >0) ? "You Clicked " + 
listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text  : "Please select an item.";

MessageBox.Show(msg);
```